# How to use FOR XML PATH to create empty tag

Tags: xml, for-xml-path

This is my first time using FOR XML PATH. After searching up and down I got to it to work almost as I want it to be

```
Select * from GTracking FOR XML PATH('TRANSACTION'), ROOT('TRANSACTIONS'),ELEMENTS
```

Except that when the value is NULL I got no tag (which is expected according to MSDN) then I changed the value to empty string (as is ""). This change creates empty tag correctly displayed in IE .

```
<ADDRESS_1> 100 - 3th ST </ADDRESS_1>
<ADDRESS_2/>
```

However when I use Notepad to open the XML it appears to have line ending as the value for ADDRESS_2 tag so it look like this

```
<ADDRESS_1> 100 - 3th ST </ADDRESS_1>
<ADDRESS_2>
</ADDRESS_2>
```

How do I know if the XML is in proper format? How to fix this problem if I want empty tag.